# How to obtain part scores in Object Detection with Discriminatively Trained Part Based Models

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, object-recognition

The code which is available at http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/latent/voc-release5.tgz is widely used in object detection. There is a **imgdetect** function which returns **ds**, **bs** and **trees**. It seems **ds** contains detection boxes and **bs** contains which of the filters used for detection responded in the image, while **trees** contains some information about the part scores. I was not able to find out how to get the part scores using **trees** and **bs**. Basically, given a detection box, I would like to find out which filters responded in detection and what was the score for each filter (sub part) which was used for detecting an object.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this, at the end of gdetect_parse.m, add the following lines, the bounding boxes (x1, x2, y1, y2) would correspond to the boxes in **bs** and the scores would be in the second last row in trees{i}

node_id = 8; //ensure that it is a leaf node, i.e second row of trees{i} should be 1

tree_id = 1; //one of the detection trees

scale = (model.sbin/pyra.scales(trees{tree_id}(8, node_id)));

x1 = (trees{tree_id}(6, node_id) - 1 - pyra.padx*(2^trees{tree_id}(9, node_id)))*scale + 1

y1 = (trees{tree_id}(7, node_id) - 1 - pyra.pady*(2^trees{tree_id}(9, node_id)))*scale + 1

filter_id = model.symbols(trees{1}(3, node_id)).filter;

fx = model.filters(filter_id).size(2);

fy = model.filters(filter_id).size(1);

x2 = x1 + fx*scale - 1

y2 = y1 + fy*scale - 1