# How to obtain part scores and bbox coordinates (or centroid) for detected object using Discriminatively Trained Part Based Model

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, object-recognition

I have a same question asked at ([How to obtain part scores in Object Detection with Discriminatively Trained Part Based Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010739/how-to-obtain-part-scores-in-object-detection-with-discriminatively-trained-part/32132893#32132893))

Though, I almost copied the same question here as well.

I am using the code available at http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/latent/voc-release5.tgz for object detection. I am not able to find out bbox coordinates or centroid and the part scores. All I want to do is I need bbox coordinates and given a detection box, I need to find out which filters responded in detection and what was the score for each filter (sub part) which was used for detecting an object.

Though, the author provided the solution but I am having problem with it and here is what happens when I tried his provided solution.

"Too many outputs requested. Most likely cause is missing [ ] around left hand side that has a comma separated list expansion."

Also, when I tried to debug it seems "filter_id" is empty. I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me please?

I posted my question there but I posted my question as an answer that was not allowed and its no more there and I can't comment on his answer (I don't have enough reputation).

(I don't know how to tag the author of that question if anyone can do it for me it would be great)

I am using MATLAB with OS X Yosemite.

Thanks!